# segfault when trying to modify a pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why do I get segfault when I try to modify a pointer to an array ?
My example is :

```
void delete_string(char** string) {
    while (*string[0] != '\0') {
    *string = *string + 1;
    }
}
int main() {
    char aux1[] = "a string";
    delete_string(&aux1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your while loop loops forever

Comment: Your types aren't correct. You're probably ignoring all your compiler diagnostics, which means that it's going to be very frustrating for both you and Stack Overflow.

Comment: valgrind says segfault is on line : while (*string[0] != '\0')

Comment: Related: `char**` and a `char (*)[9]` aren't the same thing. Don't assume they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User3461734's answer is factually correct but doesn't really explain why. The first clue is in the compiler warning you would have received:

```
t.c:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘delete_string’ from incompatible pointer type
t.c:1: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[9]’
```

Your function is expecting a pointer to a pointer to a character. You are effectively giving it a pointer to the beginning of an array of 9 characters.

This expression:

```
*string[0] != '\0'
```

is telling it de-reference the supplied pointer. You have given it a pointer to a string containing the characters "a string" - it is interpreting those characters as a pointer, rather than a set of characters. The pointer points to something like address 0x676e697274732061 (or at least on my 64bit intel based system it does). If you look closely you will see that this address is the ascii characters of your string, in reverse (61='a', 20=' ', 73='s', etc).

If you were to change the declaration of aux1 to this:

```
char *aux1 = "a string";
```

it would work, because now you are declaring a pointer variable (of type char*) which is initialized to point to an area of read-only memory containing the characters "a string". When you  pass &aux1 to your function, you are passing it a pointer to a pointer variable, which is what your function expects.

However, it probably won't be doing what you want, reading the rest of your code. At the end of the function, the aux1 pointer will be pointing at the null termination of the string. It is not really clear to me how that is deleting the string or what you would be doing with the pointer after that.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the segfault, you have to change line 7, replacing:

`char aux1[] = ""`

with:

`char *aux1 = "a string"`